# Complex filtering using ID from SELECT statement as filter on the Supabase client?

Tags: supabase

I have 3 tables "worksheet", "profile". "profileWorksheet".

"profileWorksheet" is a join table.

```
Running the following SQL query returns what I need:

select
  *
from
  worksheet
where
  id in (
    select
      worksheet
    from
      "profilesWorksheet"
    where
      profile = '123'
  )
```

Can I run this on the client? Can the `.eq` function handle something this complex?

Answer (score 0):

With the client library alone you wouldn't be able to build out the query you are looking for, but you can create a [database function](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions) and call it from the client.